# Spring MockMvc Passing Nested Form Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have the following form

```
public class MyForm {
private Account account;
}

public class Account {
private String firstName;
}
```

How do I pass firstName parameter?
(The following approach does not work)

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/xyz")
                .param("account.firstName", "John"))
                .andExpect(model().hasErrors())
                .andExpect(view().name("/xyz"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue. Since I am using standalone setup I had to define validator and messagesource.

```
void setupTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(getController())
                .setValidator(getValidator())
                .alwaysDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .build()
    }

    private MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return messageSource;
    }

    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        def validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean()
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(getMessageSource());

        return validator;
    }
```